# Create a function to fetch sub-string from string in the column of the data set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set in which one of the columns is text. I want to create a function to fetch the string based on the input( if this string has this substring print the string). I have written a function but not sure why it'snot working.

```
def update_text("selected_text"):
    for text in df['Activity Name']:
        if "selected_text" in text:
            print(text)
```

Comment: can you provide an [mcve] please? sample df and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with sample data as below:

```
import pandas as pd

def update_text(selected_text):
    for text in df['Activity Name']:
        if selected_text in text:
            print(text)

df = pd.DataFrame(['hello monkey', 'welcome'], columns=['Activity Name'])

update_text('hello')
```

Please the result as below:

```
hello monkey
```

For the new question:

```
import pandas as pd

def update_text(df, selected_text):
    dfnew = df.loc[df['Activity Name'].str.contains(selected_text)]
    return dfnew

df = pd.DataFrame(['hello monkey', 'welcome'], columns=['Activity Name'])
dfnew = update_text(df, 'hello')

print (dfnew)
```

```
  Activity Name
0  hello monkey
```

Comment: your answer works, thanks for that. Is there a way I can print the whole dataset df and assigned it to new name something like dfnew

Comment: @Ardy Could you let me know an example what you want?  There are various ways to handle data depends on the purpose.

Comment: def update_text(df, selected_text):
          dfnew = []
          for text in df['Activity Name']:
                if selected_text in text:
                    dfnew.append(df.df["Activity Name"].str.contains(selected_text))

Comment: Create a new data frame based on the selected_text above.  I have columns ('Activity name, start, longitude, Latitude, type, cost). So based on the text in the activity column. if the selected_text is in one of the rows of the column activity name, then filter the data frame, after filtering it assign it a new data frame with diffrent name somthing like dfnew. I hope i am not confusing you

Comment: @Ardy I hope it is your expectation.

Comment: This works, Thank you. But if I reference dfnew separately after running the function it's returning empty data frame. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ardy Sorry. I think I can give the exact code if you give me more code.

Comment: def update_text(Selected_text):
    for text in df['Activity Name']:
        if Selected_text in text:
            dfnew = df.loc[df['Activity Name'].str.contains(Selected_text)]
Update(Selected_text)

Comment: But when I run above code and reference dfnew. I am getting an empty data frame @yaho cho

Comment: @Ardy You don't need to use `for loop and if statement`. You can use my code without `for loop and if statement` in `update_text` function.

Comment: Great. Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for